# Getting error when try to make payment with new card in stripe subscriptions

Tags: stripe-payments, laravel-5.8, laravel-cashier

I am using *Laravel Cashier* and while working on creating a stripe subscription and when I try to pay using failed test card number 4000008260003178 then it is going in my `catch()` but creating a subscription with *Incomplete payment* and *Invoice is Open*.

```
try {
    return $subscription = $member->newSubscription('main', $planId)->withMetadata($metaArray)->create($paymentMethod);    
} catch (IncompletePayment $exception) {
    ErrorLog::create(['module'=>'Stripe payment error: ,'error'=>$exception->payment->id."-".$exception->getMessage()]);
    return false;
}
```

So, when I again try in my frontend to pay using correct card. I am getting below *Javascript error*.  Could you all please guide how to resolve this error. I am really getting stuck in this from long time. Eagerly looking for your help.

```
error: {code: "setup_intent_unexpected_state",…}
code: "setup_intent_unexpected_state"
doc_url: "https://stripe.com/docs/error-codes/setup-intent-unexpected-state"
message: "You cannot update this SetupIntent because it has already succeeded."
setup_intent: {id: "seti_1GdZmxIG6uR48z4R5hRjLsFp", object: "setup_intent", cancellation_reason: null,…}
cancellation_reason: null
client_secret: "seti_1GdZmxIG6uR48z4R5hRjLsFp_secret_HBxiiqS1kVmCTmzUMWtdUOmOENsEKEc"
created: 1588243123
description: null
id: "seti_1GdZmxIG6uR48z4R5hRjLsFp"
last_setup_error: null
livemode: false
next_action: null
object: "setup_intent"
payment_method: "pm_1GdZnCIG6uR48z4Ro4OQbcLO"
payment_method_types: ["card"]
status: "succeeded"
usage: "off_session"
type: "invalid_request_error"
```

Comment: Sounds like you're creating subscriptions with incomplete subscriptions enabled. That's [documented here](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/overview#incomplete), and you can also [specify the behavior](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create#create_subscription-payment_behavior) for incomplete subscriptions on creation.

Comment: I am using laravel cashier and it automatically create a subscription with incomplete status. Didn't find option to set payment_behaviour...